# VBA to Concatenate a Text String with NOW Formula that provides the Current Date and Time

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code and have been trying to work out and research code that I may insert that will Concatenate a Text String "Last Refreshed" with the Time and Date code

```
With Sheets("Chart Of Accounts").Range("B2")
    .Value = Now()
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
End With
```

within the code below. At the moment the Code writes the Date and Time to Cell B2 with static Text "Last Refreshed" in Cell A2. I am wanting the Text String to Concatenate with the Date and Time within the VBA Code and write it to a designated Cell in the Sheet.

```
Public Sub ChartOfAccountsOnly()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim Lastrow As Long

Columns("N:N").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("B1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Range("A4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("N4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - GAL Chart Of Accounts").Refresh
    
Range("O4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("O4:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

With Sheets("Chart Of Accounts").Range("B2")
    .Value = Now()
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
End With

End Sub
```

[image: Chart Of Accounts]

Comment: `.Value = "Last Refreshed " & Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: Thank you @BigBen works a charm, thank you.

Comment: To keep the date 'alive', try `.NumberFormat = """Last Refreshed"" dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`.

Answer (score 2):

### Improve Code

- Create a copy of your workbook to test the code because some of the improvements may not apply.
- Feel free to share what didn't apply in the comments below so it can be fixed.

```vb
Sub ChartOfAccountsOnly()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Chart Of Accounts")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    ws.Columns("N").ClearContents
    ws.Range("B1").Value = ws.Range("A1").Value
        
    Dim rg As Range
        
    With ws.Range("A4")
        Set rg = .Resize(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column) _
            .End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    rg.EntireRow.Columns("N").Value = rg.Value
    
    wb.Connections("Query - GAL Chart Of Accounts").Refresh
    
    With rg.EntireRow.Columns("O")
        .Formula = .Cells(1).Formula
    End With
        
    With ws.Range("B2")
        .Value = Now()
        ' To preserve the date, just change the format.
        .NumberFormat = """Last refreshed "" dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    End With

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Done.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @VBasic2008 I will give that a try. appreciated.